How Azure DevOps Pipeline condition evaluates parameters?
Given the following Azure DevOps pipeline template:
parameters:
  - name: AUTH_TYPE
    type: string

steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Parameter print
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: echo "AUTH_TYPE = '${{ parameters.AUTH_TYPE }}'"

  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Variable print
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: echo "AUTH_TYPE = '${{ variables.AUTH_TYPE }}'"


  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: OIDC auth
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: echo OIDC authentication
    condition: ${{ eq(parameters.AUTH_TYPE, 'oidc') }}
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Password auth
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: echo Password authentication
    condition: ${{ eq(parameters.AUTH_TYPE, 'password') }}

Calling:
# ...
variables:
  - group: pipeline-vars

steps:
  - checkout: shared-library
  - template: pipeline-templates/auth.yaml@shared-library
    parameters:
      AUTH_TYPE: $(AUTH_TYPE)

The problem is, the Parameter print outputs the AUTH_TYPE value correctly (oidc in the example) but the corresponding OIDC auth task condition evaluates to false (it is skipped in the pipeline run).
Can anyone help me what is wrong with this? I am totally new in Azure DevOps Pipelines and I currently struggling with understanding how the templates evaluated by the runtime.

Hi, you can check the answers to know more about how the templates evaluated by the runtime. Looking forward to your update.

In your Calling YAML, you are passing $(AUTH_TYPE) as a parameter to the template. The $(AUTH_TYPE) appears to be a variable defined within the pipeline-vars variable group.
In the Context of Template expressions:

Within a template expression, you have access to the parameters context that contains the values of parameters passed in. Additionally, you have access to the variables context that contains all the variables specified in the YAML file plus many of the predefined variables (noted on each variable in that article). Importantly, it doesn't have runtime variables such as those stored on the pipeline or given when you start a run. Template expansion happens early in the run, so those variables aren't available.

In your case, the parameter in condition: ${{ eq(parameters.AUTH_TYPE, 'oidc') }} is evaluated at compile time. At compile time, the variable $(AUTH_TYPE) is not available and you are passing the empty $(AUTH_TYPE) as a parameter to the template, so the parameters.AUTH_TYPE is also empty.  This is why the condition in your task evaluates to false.
To make the pipeline template work as you want, you can define AUTH_TYPE as parameters instead of the variable.
parameters:
  - name: AUTH_TYPE
    type: string
    default: 'oidc' # or 'password', depending on what you want

steps:
  - checkout: shared-library
  - template: pipeline-templates/auth.yaml@shared-library
    parameters:
      AUTH_TYPE: ${{ parameters.AUTH_TYPE }}



Your template yaml looks good with slight modification, I have just test it and the OIDC auth condition works.
But you can not pass the variable into template parameters. the template yaml be compiled to a big-yaml will accept the parameters at compile time, but variables values work in run-time.
parameters:
- name: AUTH_TYPE
  type: string
  default: 'oidc'

variables:
- name: var1
  value: ${{ parameters.AUTH_TYPE }} 

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Parameter print
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo "AUTH_TYPE = ${{ parameters.AUTH_TYPE }}"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Variable print
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo "AUTH_TYPE = ${{ variables.var1 }}"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: OIDC auth
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo OIDC authentication
  condition: ${{ eq(parameters.AUTH_TYPE, 'oidc') }}
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Password auth
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo Password authentication
  condition: ${{ eq(parameters.AUTH_TYPE, 'password') }}


